# problem with adding space to anchor text in chrome and ie(probably text-indent?)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

i have an element with multiple css classes and it goes about like this:

```
 <a href="asdad" class="icon make-default ss_sprite ss_bullet_white">Make Default</a>
```

chrome and ie show it like this: http://grab.by/9OXe

while firefox shows it like this: http://grab.by/9OXs

Take note that i highlighted the a element for you with firebug opened up(that's all the styles)

I preferred the screenshot over jsfiddle(as i normally would comment on people) because the screenie shows what I am wondering about: why chrome and ie show that anchor block differently. I know to expect browsers not rendering stuff the same(especially ie vs webkit, but for chrome and ie to agree is unusual) and I have a reset.css(960's reset)

Is there something I'm missing? I had a solution to add a width to the icon class, BUT i am wondering why I need to do that.

**UPDATE**

While writing this question I had the chance to change the a to this:

```
 <a href="asdad" class="icon make-default ss_sprite ss_bullet_white">Default</a>
```

because if you can see the black bullet there, it was using the same classes and it was fixed. The problem now is that **ANYTHING WITH SPACES** as the anchor text will break the thing in IE and chrome. Any explanations why?

(Also my code is degrading gracefully so even without the styles it should show that Make Default text(I know I'm not showing it by using the negative indent trick, but in the case of no css, it should show that Make Default text so I don't plan on changing it as much as possible)

Comment: You need to show more of your CSS; elements are affected by styles on elements around them and their parents.

Comment: as i said above, it seems that the problem is with text-indent or something that doesn't give the anchor tag any width in firefox(thus making it look fixed) while giving it 41px in chrome

Answer (score 0):

Taking into consideration your update,

have you tried `white-space:nowrap;` or instead of using spaces, to use non-breaking-spaces `&nbsp;` ?

Of-course a live fiddle or more html/css around the problem could help us trouble-shoot better.